# How to reference "active/selected" chart data point in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I am looking for a way to reference active/selected chart data point in Excel using VBA.

Imagine I have a line chart, which I would like to add an error bar to. But, I do not want to add error bars to the whole series, but only to ONE, selected point. See the screen below:

[image]

What I want to do is to add a vertical error bar that would point down to the X-axis, something like this:
[image]

I KNOW how to do it in Excel, there are multiple ways, for example, adding a new one-point series and then adding an error bar. There are other ways. The issue I have is HOW to reference active/selected data point.

If I would choose to create a new, one point series, I need to know the point number to do that. I know (I used it) that you can reference points with Points object/method. Sadly, I do not know how to extract the selected point number, coordinates, whatever, so I can work with it later on in my project.

I cannot add any code, as everything I have done is formatting and playing with error bars, as well as iterating through existing, ALL data points (the code would have no use in this case). What I am looking for is THE selected point information, so I could refer to it as .Point(x) with x being my previously extracted point number, without being forced to reference point number right away like .Point(8) (I do not know the specific number, as I just clicked on it).

I have seen the way to extract it using chart events, but this is a an overkill for what I want to do in my little simple project (especially how to reference the "extracted" point in other macros, outside the class module).

Any ideas? All help is greatly appreciated, as I am lost after 3 days of trying to find the way to reference it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the index, you can parse the point's [`Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.point.name), which is in the format:

`S<series number>P<point number>`

```
Sub Test()
    If TypeOf Selection Is Point Then        
        Dim p as Point
        Set p = Selection

        Debug.Print CLng(Split(p.Name, "P")(1)) ' this is p's index
    End If
End Sub
```

To get more information about that point, such as the x and y values, perhaps you could do the following:

```
Sub Test()
    If TypeOf Selection Is Point Then
        Dim p As Point
        Set p = Selection

        Dim i As Long
        i = CLng(Split(p.Name, "P")(1))

        Dim s As Series
        Set s = p.Parent

        Debug.Print s.Values(i) ' Values is a one-based array so you can use the point index to get its corresponding value
        Debug.Print s.XValues(i)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is pure perfection! Thank you very much. Is there any way to extract more information about the Point? Selected series value at that point etc?